# Manipulate/bypass md5 in php?

Tags: php, md5

There is a programm from my University (IT-Securiy) where you have to try capturing "flags" by manipulating php or html code for example. We only see the code below and the programm runs on a website of them. So we need to somehow manipulate the url or something like this... but I really stuck on this one here:

```
<?php
require_once '_flags.php';


highlight_file(__FILE__);


if (isset($_GET['pw']) &&
        md5($_GET['pw']) == '0e13371337133713371337133713371337') {
    echo $doyouphp3_flag;
}
```

I know, that I have to submit a password by adding ...

```
?pw=...
```

... at the end of the url, but I just dont know what...
Is there any way to bypass the md5 function for example, because I dont think they want me to brutforce the password...

Hope someone can help me or at least give me a hint.

Marius

Comment: Unsalted MD5 is easily brute-forcable.

Comment: @SLaks, `0e13371337133713371337133713371337` isn't a valid md5 hash

Comment: @Marius, here a suggest: `var_dump("0e321651651621651" == '0e13371337133713371337133713371337');`. You just need to find the right hash

Comment: Yes that was what I was told on every site which "decrypts" md5....

Comment: `md5('c9b5f0ad89bb4789d09ab09b2a14cadb')` = '0e13371337133713371337133713371337' [googled it](http://md5.gromweb.com/?md5=c9b5f0ad89bb4789d09ab09b2a14cadb)

Comment: or `md5("240610708") == '0e13371337133713371337133713371337'`

Comment: @Federkun: wow nice :o 240610708 was right. How did you know?

Comment: that's the real question, isn't it?

Comment: i would suggest you study, instead of getting the answers here. if you know how md5 works, without a salt you can easily reverse the process.

Comment: the answer here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php -> `If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically. `

Comment: I already said that `0e13371337133713371337133713371337` IS NOT a valid md5 hash. The trick here is how php string comparison works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to observe that `0e13371337133713371337133713371337` is a number, and it isn't a valid md5 hash.

Then you need to know how php loose comparison (with the `==` operator) involving numerical strings works. You can read that on the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves
>   numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the
>   comparison performed numerically.

So, now you know that

```
var_dump('0' == '0e13371337133713371337133713371337'); // true
var_dump('0e123' == '0e13371337133713371337133713371337'); // true
var_dump('0e65165165165165' == '0e13371337133713371337133713371337'); // true
```

So, you just need to find a md5 hash that's also a number.

The md5 hash of `240610708` is `0e462097431906509019562988736854`, and `"0e13371337133713371337133713371337" == "0e462097431906509019562988736854"` is true. So you can use that. But also `QNKCDZO` should works just fine.

What's the lesson here? That `md5('240610708') == md5('QNKCDZO')` is `true` and it's dangerous, and that you should use `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. I have to admit, that I still doesn't understand it completely and fell pretty stupid.. :D  
Both strings are converted to numbers (because of the 'e' to float's). But then both are different floats, but when comparing them in php it results a true? But that's probably because I just dont understand the problem with the numerical comparison. That should become clear when I learn more about php... Thanks for your help

Comment: if seems strange it's because it is. php is... weird. let say weird.

Comment: haha ok thanks for the hint^^ yes it seems pretty strange, if you worked with java, c++ & co and now php. but thx anyways